# How do I use an image as a `ChartLabel`?

Tags: plotting, image, labeling, charts

I'm trying to use an image as a `ChartLabel` and I'm getting strange results.

Here is a bar chart, with labels, that looks ok:

[image: chart ok]

But when I try to replace the "A" label with an image, the output is confusing:

[image: chart busted]

Specifically, the image overlaps the plot and is scaled weirdly.

I'd like it to be small, and centered, as the "A" label is in the image above.

What's the right way to use an image as a `ChartLabel`?

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** The option [`LabelingSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingSize.html) provides a convenient way to size the images.

```
images = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Elaine", "Mandrill"};

is = 60;
bs = .2; 

BarChart[Thread[Labeled[{1, 2, 3}, images, Below]], 
 BarSpacing -> bs, LabelingSize -> is (1 - bs), ImageSize -> 1 -> is]
```

[image]

With `is = 120` and `bs = .3` we get:

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
images = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Elaine", "Mandrill"};

BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> 
 Placed[Thumbnail[#, Tiny] & /@ images, Axis, Panel[#, FrameMargins -> 0] &]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `Magnify` instead of `Thumbnail`:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[images, Axis, Framed[Magnify[#, .3], FrameStyle -> None] &]]
```

[image]

Few more alternatives that produce similar pictures:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> (Framed[Magnify[#, .3], FrameStyle->None] & /@ images)]
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> Placed[Pane[Magnify[#, .1]] & /@ images, Axis]]
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels->Placed[Framed[Magnify[#, .3], 
  FrameStyle -> None]& /@ images, Axis]]
```

Comment: I just hope that the vertical scale does not represent human beauty.

Comment: Thanks, @kguler. I didn't know about `Placed` or `Thumbnail` or `Panel`. There is much to learn.

Comment: Harold, my pleasure.

Comment: @JohnMorganthau, let's hope so indeed:)

Comment: Was doing this again today and found that `Pane` worked best. Thanks again for this answer, and good luck to future searchers!

Answer (score 1):

How about using `ChartElements` instead of `ChartLabels`.

```
images = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Mandrill"};

BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ChartElements -> {images, None}]
```

[image]